# Java Downcasting Reference parameter interface

Tags: java, interface, downcast

I writing a fraction calculator project.I'm trying to write the multiply method. And I need to downcast reference parameter FractionInterface to Fraction if I want to use it as SimpleFraction.
Here's the FractionInterface:

```
public interface FractionInterface {
    public void setFraction(int num, int den);

    public void simplifyFraction();

    public double toDouble();

    public FractionInterface add(FractionInterface secondFraction);

    public FractionInterface subtract(FractionInterface secondFraction);

    public FractionInterface multiply(FractionInterface secondFraction);

    public FractionInterface divide(FractionInterface secondFraction);
}
```

Here's the method:

```
public FractionInterface multiply(FractionInterface secondFraction) {
    FractionInterface f = new Fraction(num,den);
    Fraction result = new Fraction((this.num * f.num),(this.den * f.den));//error:num cannot be resolved or is not a field
    return result;
}   // end multiply
```

Comment: what do you expect `f.num` to be? The question needs more details over the implemented class and attributes shared in the code above.

Comment: You have no num property defined in your FractionInterface class. No den property either. You can't use properties that don't exist.

Comment: I just figured it out. it should be Fraction f = (Fraction) secondFraction;

Comment: If that implementation is in `Fraction` class: The interface only call for `secondFraction` to be of type `FractionInterface`. Casting it without checks could fail.

Answer (score 0):

> error:num cannot be resolved or is not a field

`f` is a reference of type `FractionInterface`. You cannot access class fields through an interface reference; you need to downcast `f` to `Fraction` *before* you access its `num` and `den` fields.

Moving on, `secondFraction` nowhere is being used in the body of the function.